# K-fold cross validation in azure ML

Tags: azure, azure-machine-learning-service, automl, azure-auto-ml

I am currently training a model using an azure ML pipeline that i build with sdk. I am trying to add cross-validation to my ml step. I have noticed that you can add this in the parameters when you configure the autoML. My dataset consists of 30% label 0 and 70% label 1.

My question is, does azure autoML stratify data when performing the cross-validation? If not i would have to do the split/stratify myself before passing it to autoML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Auto ML can stratify the data when performing cross-validation. The following procedure needs to be followed to perform cross-validation

[image]

Create the workspace resource.

[image]

After giving all the details, click on create

[image]

Launch the Studio and go to AutoML and click on New Automated ML job

[image]

Upload the dataset from here and give the basic details required.

[image]

Dataset uploaded with some basic categories

[image]

After uploading dataset use that dataset for the prediction model performance

[image]

Here for prediction, we can choose the k-fold cross validation for validation type and number of cross validations as 5. There is no split we are performing. The model will perform according to the validation requirements.